# strikeout/strikethrough specific text within the same column and rows in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, strikethrough

I have this problem where I want to strikeout a specific text in crystal reports. I mean I do not want to strikeout the entire string in that column I am using crystal reports in visual studio.

Here is the image:

I format the `encumbrances` column and check the strikeout as shown in the image below:

[image: Format Editor]

This next image is i input a script where if the string contains "*" it will strikeout the string. This is not what I wanted. What I want is that strikeout only the strings after the asterisk. I mean all of the strings after the asterisk should be strikeout and all of the strings before the asterisk should not be strikeout.

[image: Format]

This is the result using the current script I have. As you can see all of the text is strikeout. What I want is that the text "CANCELLED" should only be strikeout since it is after the asterisk and the text "ANOTHER ENCUMBRANCES" should not be strikeout since it is before the asterisk.

[image: result]

How to solve this problem? Is this possible? I know my script is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As Crystal Reports can only display one font-style inside one formula field, you have to create two formulas and cut the text in two parts.

Create following formulas and put them inside a text-object.

(On the `AfterAsterisk`-formula tick the `Strikeout`-checkmark.)

**BeforeAsterisk**

```
If InStr({td_table.ENCUMBRANCES}, "*") > 0 Then
    Left({td_table.ENCUMBRANCES}, InStr({td_table.ENCUMBRANCES}, "*")-1)
```

**AfterAsterisk**

```
If InStr({td_table.ENCUMBRANCES}, "*") > 0 Then
    Mid({td_table.ENCUMBRANCES}, InStr({td_table.ENCUMBRANCES}, "*"))
```

Comment: where do i put this formulas? I'm still new to using formulas in crystal reports

Comment: You have to create two new formula-fields. Put a text-object on the report and put the two formula-fields inside the text-object (drag&drop).

Comment: do i need to install crystal report? because I'm using crystal report in visual studio

Comment: No, just create new formula-fields. You should find this in "Field Explorer". This is a really basic task in Crystal Reports. If still not clear, watch a tutorial video.

Comment: how can i insert this formulas to my database fields?

Comment: my fields is not text object but field object

Comment: They don't have to be inserted into the database. Re-read my answer and as already mentioned, if you're not aware of what a [formula-field](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/crystal_reports/creating_modifying_formulas.htm) or [text-object](http://kb.blackbaud.com/articles/Article/46084) is, you should definitely first get informed by taking a tutorial or whatever. I don't want to be harsh, but SO is not here to teach you such basics.